# send more than 100 emails using thrid party apps in gsuite

Tags: google-forms, email, google-workspace-for-business

I am using G Suite app "Form Confirmation Emails" to send a customized mail in response when a user fills the form and submits their details.
Everything is going on well but after 100 emails the messages get bounced/blocked.
Below is the exact message I get.
**Your message to abcd@gmail.com has been blocked. See technical details below for more information.** The link they take me to is https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596?visit_id=637316916397394156-1334392294&rd=1

I also understand that emails sent using Gmail API or via SMTP has the limit 100.

I am also using another ADD-ON autocrat for sending certificates for people who have filled the form automatically. Even this after 100 emails bounces/blocked because of the limit.

So my question is how can I increase this limit, is there any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have answer this question in Stack overflow  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117165/increasing-google-apps-script-mailapp-email-limit-for-personal-account/63127571#63127571).

I report the same here anyway, but long story short, you need to use a G suite or a payment account and there is no workaround:

1

In order to have 1,500* / day of Email recipients per day you need to upgrade at least to G Suite Basic.

Check out this art: [Current quotas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117165/increasing-google-apps-script-mailapp-email-limit-for-personal-account/63127571#63127571)

Compare G Suite Editions: https://gsuite.google.com/compare-editions/

However As you stated you want to still use Apps Script with the personal account and obviously this limits won't apply. You would need to use the new G Suite account.

Having said that, creating a G suite Basic account it doesn't necessarily need to be a 'Business account' but it can be a 'personal account.' You would need to buy a domain name and create a new email address with the new domain name, for instance: myuser@mydomain.com.

However Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users (You can do a manual payment of 30 $). [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117165/increasing-google-apps-script-mailapp-email-limit-for-personal-account/63127571#63127571): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Regarding your question 'Will I be able to access the 1500 email limit from my personal account' and 'Is there a way then to increase the limit for the personal account?'

You can't, the only solution is to go for a G Suite account.

Comment: I already have a business account in G Suite. That is what I am using to send the emails. So initially I thought it would send mails as it a G suite account. But when emails crossed more than 100 it would bounce/block. Do we need to change some settings with the admin?

Comment: How long have you had this Business account?

Comment: This is  some usniversity account. Its been there since many years. I dont know the exact number.

Comment: Best thing then is  Contact G Suite support: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&ref_topic=7067151